# Set grid row height equal to window height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid with 1 row and I want that row to span the entire length of the page (or more if there is content inside that is longer than the length of the page). Height 100% is not working nor setting template-rows to 1fr.

HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div className="grid calendar">
        <div className="grid-item">
            Some content will be inside each of these
        </div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
  border-left: 4px #e5e7eb solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`height 100%` doesn't work cause it's `100%` of parent element, that is `0` in your case, cause you didn't defined it. So you can either set the container height of `100vh` and then yours `100%` in `.grid` will work or you can change unit of the `.grid` height to `vh`.

`100vh` is something you are looking for.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.grid-item {
  border-left: 4px #e5e7eb solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="grid calendar">
        <div class="grid-item">
            Some content will be inside each of these
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
        <div class="grid-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` and `vw`
For example:

**100vh = 100%(screen height)**

**100vw = 100%(screen width)**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.grid-item {
  border-left: 4px #e5e7eb solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <div className="grid calendar">
          <div className="grid-item">
               Some content will be inside each of these
          </div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
          <div className="grid-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```